# Turning some numbers in a string into int value (without atoi) while validating that a string meets the conditions

Tags: c++

I wanted to write this code without using atoi.

edit* question did not make sense for readers and it was too long. sorry for being vague with everything.

Comment: you can't use `atoi`? use `atol` `atoll` or `stringstream` ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: *"i am not allowed to use atoi"* - deprecated, and for good reasons - there is `strtol` as alternative - or are you not allowed to use *any* converting functions?

Comment: Off-topic: after `return ...;` within your if, you do not need `else` any more. Some even consider this bad coding style... For boolean values, do not compare against equality (`== true`, `== false`; this *definitely* is bad style!), just check the condition itself (`if(condition)`, `if(!condition)`, `assert(condition)`, `assert(!condition)`. Definitely worst: `if(condition) return true; else return false;` needlessly verbose, just do: `return condition;` (condition negated, if need be...) instead.

Comment: OT again: return is not a function, do not put parentheses around the values returned...

Comment: wouldn't regex solve this pretty neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several fundamental problems:

```
if (firsttimeThru)
{
    firsttimeThru = false;

    int result = number(auctionString, stringPosition);
    if (result > 0)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // too early!
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

If you return here, you have checked, if a number follows 'L'/'l', but there might yet follow something - valid or not...

```
default:
    return false;
    // break; // not necessary (unreachable anyway); you return previously, don't you?
```

You will now reject *any* input, including the 'B' (provided you did not return as shown above...).

Assuming you iterate over the whole loop successfully (skipping the premature return), you need a default return value:

```
for(...) {}
// assuming you returned on error previously:
return true;
```

Now how to do better? I am now not pretty sure what you really are after, so I try to deduce a pattern from your example string "L500B50B+100":

`L` or `l` followed by any non-negative integral number followed by another single character followed by another non-negative integral followed by another letter followed by `+` followed by another non-negative integral...

```
bool isValidEbayListingString(string auctionString)
{
    // i prefer operating on character data (allows to use strtol),
    // you could use the string's iterator instead:
#if 0
    std::string::const_iterator data = auctionString.begin();
    // instead of checking for *data ==/!= 0, you then need
    // to check for data ==/!= auctionString().end()
    // additionally, you explicitly need to check for empty string!
#else
    char const* data = auctionString.c_str();
#endif
    if(*data == 'L' || *data == 'l')
        // checks for string length being 0, too, as *data would be 0 then...
    {
        ++data;
        // now non-negative integral required:
#if 0
        char* end;
        unsigned long number = strtoul(data, &end, 10);
        if(end == data || errno == ERANGE)
            // no data or too large number;
            // how many digits do you want to allow???
            // if need be, consider unsigned long long and strtoull...
        {
            return false;
        }
#else
        // assuming you do not need the number, much easier:
        if(!*data) // need at least one digit
        {
            return false;
        }
        while(*data && isdigit((unsigned char)*data))
            ++data;
        // pack this piece of code into a function for reuse...
#endif
        if(*data && *data != 'L' && *data != 'l')
            // a letter must follow, but non of L/l
        {
            ++data;

            // check for digits just as above (call the function)...

            if(*data && *data != 'L' && *data != 'l' && data[1] == '+')
                // another letter except L/l, next one must be '+'
            {
                data += 2;

                // check for digits just as above...

                return *data == 0; // we must now have reached the string's end!
            }
        }
    }
    // any other case:
    return false;
}
```

If I guessed the wrong pattern, you'll need some adjustments, of course...